# php display query results on same page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is a form in my index page where user will select an option and click submit. On submitting it'll be posted in "display.php" file where i'm fetching data from database.

index page code:

```
<form action="display.php" method="post">
<select name="mnth">
<option value="Jan">January</option>
<option value="Feb">February</option>
<option value="Mar">March</option>
<option value="Apr">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="Jun">June</option>
<option value="Jul">July</option>
<option value="Aug">August</option>
<option value="Sep">September</option>
<option value="Oct">October</option>
<option value="Nov">November</option>
<option value="Dec">December</option>
</select>
<input id="abc" type="submit" name="Display"></input> 
</form>
```

The display.php file contains the following php code which fetches data from table and displays it in a tabular form in a different white page.
But want to display this table in my index page instead. How do i do that?

```
<?php

$empid=$_COOKIE["empid"];
$deptt=$_COOKIE["deptt"];
$password=$_COOKIE["password"];

$month=$_POST["mnth"];



$empid=mysql_real_escape_string($empid);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');


$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","");
if(!$con)
{
die("Error in connection");
}

$db=mysql_select_db("swan",$con);

if(!$db)
{
 echo mysql_errno($con);
}

$query_login="SELECT * FROM `".$empid."_login` WHERE month='$month' ";
$query_logout="SELECT * FROM `".$empid."_logout` WHERE month='$month' ";
$query_hrs="SELECT * FROM `".$empid."_hrs` WHERE month='$month' ";
$result1=mysql_query($query_login,$con);
$result2=mysql_query($query_logout,$con);
$result3=mysql_query($query_hrs,$con);
$value1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$value2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$value3=mysql_fetch_array($result3);




$day=date('d');

echo '<table id="displayTable" border="1px"> <th>Date</th><th>Login_Time</th>
      <th>Logout_time</th><th>Hours</th>';


for($i=0;$i<31;$i++)
{
echo '<tr><td>'.($i+1).'</td><td>'.$value1[($i+1)].'</td><td>'.$value2[($i+1)].'</td>
<td>'.$value3[($i+1)].'</td></tr>';

}

echo '</table>';



?>
```

Comment: you want PHP code in seprate file and html code in index.php??

Answer (score 1):

You could use  `if $_POST` so it would look something like this:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
// code from display.php
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="mnth">
<option value="Jan">January</option>
<option value="Feb">February</option>
<option value="Mar">March</option>
<option value="Apr">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="Jun">June</option>
<option value="Jul">July</option>
<option value="Aug">August</option>
<option value="Sep">September</option>
<option value="Oct">October</option>
<option value="Nov">November</option>
<option value="Dec">December</option>
</select>
<input id="abc" type="submit" name="Display"></input> 
</form>
```

Comment: but i want to keep the display code in a separate file instead of putting all the code in my index page

Answer (score 0):

On Same page use - `AJAX` or `action=""` and code on same page and check if form submit or not.

**1st** Option -

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
// Do form processing, taking care of sql injections
}
else
{
// Show Form
}
```

**2nd** Option -

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yourURL",// your display.php
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
        },
        success: function(data) {console.log(data)} 
    });
```

//using jQuery for AJAX here.

2nd option usage is sexy, but hey what if JS disabled, so keep these things in your mind as well.

I am using `console.log` here, so to check it use browser console.